# How can I extract the integer from a string with mixed alphabetic, punctuation and integers in C?

Tags: c, parsing

I have a string that looks like "AGE:83". I want to take the integer "83" out of this string, and I know that I should use the "sscanf" function. However, there is no white space between this string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
const char *str = "AGE:83";
int age;

sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%d", &age);
```

This format will skip any non digits and parse an integer after that.

Note that it will fail if there are no non digit characters before the number.  To handle the case where the number can be at the start of the string, use first try a direct match:

```
if (sscanf(str, "%d", &age) != 1
&&  sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%d", &age) != 1) {
    // no number found;
    return 1;
}
// age was correctly extracted from `str`
```

Negative numbers cannot be parsed this way, unless you know the prefix does not contain a `'-'` (using format `"%*[^0-9-]%d"`)

You can also use a string function to skip the prefix and convert the rest for `atoi()` or `strtol()`:

```
age = atoi(str + strcspn(str, "0123456789"));
```

As noted by Enzo Ferber, if the format of the string is fixed and is known to start with `AGE:`, you can just convert the remainder of the string with:

```
age = atoi(str + 4);
```

But this would invoke undefined behavior if the string is shorter than 4 characters as you would be potentially dereferencing invalid addresses.

Comment: And consider whether to add one or more `%n` conversions if you need to know where the matches start and/or stop.

Comment: The solution is great. If you know the text before the age is always AGE: then you could avoid regular expressions by writing  sscanf(str, "AGE:%d", &age);

Comment: @nicomp If you know the text is always `"AGE:"` you could do: `int age = atoi(str+4);` and avoid `sscanf` altogether.